# How to duplicate strncat (original)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c-strings

My stringNAdd function will duplicate strncat (original). I cannot accept arrays as parameters, but pointers. I wonder if my code right?

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *stringNAdd(char str1[], char str2[],size_t num);
int main()
{
    char dest[50] = "Using strncat function,";
    char src[50] = " this part is added and this is ignored";
    cout<< strncat(dest, src, 20) << endl;
    cout << stringNAdd(dest, src, 20) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
    
}

char *stringNAdd(char str1[], char str2[],size_t num){
    size_t str1_len = strlen(str1);
    size_t i;
    
    for (i=0; i < num && str2[i] != '\0'; i++)
        i==num;
     str1[str1_len+i] = str2[i];
     str1[str1_len+i] = '\0';
    
    return str1;
}
```

> Output:
>
> Using strncat function, this part is added
>
> Using strncat function, this part is added

Comment: Run it. It's the best way to see if it's right.

Comment: I already run it, and it worked perfectly. I just wonder did I use a straight array.

Comment: I don't know. You will have to tell us first what is a straight array.

Comment: I have to use pointer to work with the cstrings, i.e. your functions cannot use straight arrays.  Use of arrays is only allowed to get data from the user or to pass as arguments to your functions.

Comment: We have a language or terminology problem here. Can you give us a definition or example of a "straight array"?

Comment: I still don't know what does that mean, but I can try guessing it means you shouldn't accept arrays as parameters, but pointers.

Comment: When you (attempt to) pass an array to a function, what gets passed is a pointer to the first element of the array. When/if you attempt to declare a function parameter of array type, the declaration is silently adjusted to be a pointer type. A function that receives an actual array as a parameter simply isn't allowed (though if you really insist, it *is* possible to pass a struct containing an array).

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: `str1[str1_len+1]` does not seem right. I don't see anything that changes the value of `str1_len` Typo? Should this be `str1[str1_len+i]`

Comment: I changed it already. Thanks user4581301

Comment: Looks kie you are misusing `num`. the third parameter is the max size of the completed string in `strncat`. You are using `num` to limit what you add on to the string. I also see one bit of nastiness: if `for (i=0; i < num && str2[i] != '\0'; i++)` exited because `i == num`, then `str1[str1_len+i] = '\0';` may be writing out of bounds.

Comment: If you do this kind of thing with real-word data, you'll quickly discover that `strncat` leads to mysterious crashes. It is **not** a "safe" replacement for `strcat` (for any reasonable definition of "safe"). If it hits the character limit that you pass to it, it does not write a nul terminator at the end of the string, so you can end up with an unterminated string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't do the test of both functions in the same conditions:  once you've executed [`strncat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/),  the `dest` already contains the longer concatenated version.

The second problem is that `dest` was already enlarged by 15 chars.  It has therefore an initial length of 38 chars + the null terminator before calling `stringNAdd()`.  Adding 15 more chars result in a string of 53 chars plus a null terminator, which is 4 chars longer than your array.  So you'll get a buffer overflow, hence memory corruption and undefined behavior.

But all this is related to the testing conditions: your clone works fine.

**Suggestions:**

Run your functions in distinct blocks, and define your testing variables local to that block:

```
{
char dest[50] = "Using strncat function,";
char src[50] = " this part is added and this is ignored";
cout<< strncat(dest, src, 15) << endl;
cout << strlen(dest)<<endl;
}
{
char dest[50] = "Using strncat function,";
char src[50] = " this part is added and this is ignored";
cout << stringNAdd(dest, src, 15) << endl;
}
```

Think of a more secure version of your function, in which you would have an additional argument with the total length of the destination array to prevent these errors. This would increase the security of your code.  By the way, this is what Microsoft does with [`strncat_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncat-s-strncat-s-l-wcsncat-s-wcsncat-s-l-mbsncat-s-mbsncat-s-l).

Finally, you could ask your teacher why he/she still lets you work with cstrings, when there are the so much more convenient and secure `std::string`, and that he certainly could find more modern exercises with the same pedagogical benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is equivalent based on https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/i386.subproj/strncat.c

```
#include <iostream>

char *strnadd(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    // abort if source is empty
    if (n != 0) 
    {
        // copy pointers
        char *d = dst;
        const char *s = src;

        // find end of destination str
        while (*d != 0)
            d++;

        // start copying chars from source str to the end of destination str
        // until either source string ends or number of chars copied 
        // destination string has to be long enough to accommodate source
        do 
        {
            if ((*d = *s++) == 0)
                break;
            d++;
        } 
        while (--n != 0);

        // add null termination
        *d = 0;
    }

    // return the resulting string
    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    char strCat[50];
    char strAdd[50];

    strcpy(strCat, "string1");
    strcpy(strAdd, "string1");

    char const *str2 = "string2";

    std::cout << strncat(strCat, str2, 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << strnadd(strAdd, str2, 6) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
string1string
string1string
```